# Qt tr for internationalisation does not work in main function?

Tags: string, qt, internationalization

Qt's translation function `tr` does not work in the `main` function but works fine in a QWidget member function. Why is that?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QDialog dialog; 
    QString temp = tr("dadasda");//error:tr was not declared in this scope
    dialog.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The translation function `tr` is a static method of `QObject`. Since `QWidget` is a subclass of `QObject`, `tr` is available in methods of `QWidget`, but in `main()` you have to use `QObject::tr` in order to use the function, as shown below.

```
#include <QObject>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QDialog dialog; 
    QString temp = QObject::tr("dadasda");//works fine
    dialog.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: tr works only for Q_OBJECT classes, if you want to use tr in a cpp class use QObject::tr() and lupdate. after this string is moved to QObject context in Linguist and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a really neat trick to fix this problem. I have hundreds of those static calls to QObject::tr throughout my Qt applications and feel that this creates needless clutter. I discovered that if I add the following code to the top of my source files where tr() is required:

static inline QString tr(const char *s, const char *c = nullptr, int n = -1) 
{ return QObject::tr(s, c, n); }

this issue is eliminated. After adding this inline directive, you may simply replace QObject::tr() with tr(). You may also need to add class QObject; and class QString; to the top of your files, if they, or other libraries do not already include them (this would be likely required anyway). This simple solution works very well for me!